# FragmentTabHost embedded page is cut off

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

happy Easter to all in the community !
I'm despairing in programming my FragmentTabHost Example in Android.
I'm now excercising for two days, there's no success in sight.

My aim is to open a fragment in MainActivity, placing a FragmentTabHost
on this fragment and assign another fragment in the context of the tab pages.

As you can see in screenshot, the top of the embedded page is cut off
by the header of the tab control. The button placed at top is not really visible
anymore.

I've added my code here. Where is my thinking error ? I suspect it will
be easy to fix but I'm trying in vain so far.

---

[image]

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragment = new BaseFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
}

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageResource(icon);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(title);
    return view;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.label_1, 0)),
            TabFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.label_2, 0)),
            TabFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(getTabIndicator(mTabHost.getContext(), R.string.label_3, 0)),
            TabFragment.class, null);
}
}


public class TabFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

fragment_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use TabLayout  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: If I'm changing the layout to TabLayout, the following error occurs :

04-02 12:47:33.035 6094-6094/com.example.freddy.fragmenttabhostexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.freddy.fragmenttabhostexample, PID: 6094
                                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TabLayout

Comment: Can you show the sample code where you are using TabLayout?